# CSS: Don't accept the whole div

Tags: html, css

I've created a `div` containing child divs. The child divs are supposed to have the same `background-color` as the main div (`<div id="how-it-works">`), but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions?

```css
#how-it-works{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#how-it-works h3{
    font-family: gill sans;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;  
}
#details-wrapper{
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#feature-one{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#feature-one p {
    font-family: times;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}        
#feature-one img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#feature-two{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#feature-two p{
    font-family: times;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}
#feature-two img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#feature-three{
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#feature-three p {
    font-family: times;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: justify;
}
#feature-three img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="how-it-works">

    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    <p>Text.</p>
    
    <div id="details-wrapper">
     <div id="feature-one">
            <img src="images/bild.jpg">
         <h4>TITLE</h4>
         <p>Text.</p>
        </div>
     <div id="feature-two">
         <img src="images/bild.jpg">
         <h4>TITLE</h4>
         <p>Text.</p>
     </div>
     <div id="feature-three">
         <img src="images/bild.jpg">
         <h4>TITLE</h4>
         <p>Text.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the three 'feature-*' are float.

You can set how-it-works `overflow:hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a clearfix to the `#how-it-works` container

```
#how-it-works:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

The three feature `<div>`s are floating. This takes them outside of the normal document flow which makes them not influence the height of the `#how-it-works` container. A clearfix, or in this case as Jonas Grumann mentioned adding `overflow: hidden` solves this. The clearfix however is the better option if you need e.g. a `box-shadow` on the element.

If you inspect the `#how-it-works` container in for example Chrome's DevTools you can easily see this, the feature `<div>`s aren't in the blue overlay that shows the dimensions of the `#how-it-works` container.

Comment: overflow: hidden; to #how-it-works works just as fine and is less code

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an class `.clear{ clear:both; }` and use that one under the `#feature-*` elements.

See fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72n4zvkr/)

Answer (score 0):

replace below code:

```
#how-it-works{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

with new code:

```
#how-it-works{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

**Note:** main parent DIV should set 'display' block and 'width' 100% and it fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float property from the last div element (#feature-three):

```
#feature-three {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This will make the parent div recognise at least the height of this element and paint the background.

With overflow: hidden on your parent div you won't see overlapping elements. Eventually you need then scrollbars with overflow: auto; :

```
#how-it-works {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```